# Wordpress ignore part of url

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I need to ignore part of url on specific pages. For example - www.example.com/test/111/222. Everything after "/test/" should be ignored and original "/test/" page should be opened. Now I get 404 error. Is it possible?